# Github showing "Rate Limit" screen very often, but my usual activity is 50-100 github views per day

Tags: github, limit

I'm seeing this message on the webpage:

"Access has been restricted
You have triggered a rate limit.

Please wait a few minutes before you try again;
in some cases this may take up to an hour."

I am using macOS. No external apps to access github, no background workers to access github api or anything.

What could trigger this and how to solve this problem? Can't even access my own libraries on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it was problem on Github side. Message gone after some days.